# R lang: Appending column with string

Tags: r, concatenation

I have the following data.table

```
     sku                           name
1 256573 Hotel Livemax Yokohama Tsurumi
2 256574               Hidatei Hanaougi
3 256576                Hotel Kashimaso
```

I just want to append every row in the name column with ", Japan" because they are hotel names in Japan.

I found that I can use **paste** to join strings, but how to do it to a column?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In base R simply

```
df$name <- paste0(df$name, ", Japan")
df
#     sku                                  name
#1 256573 Hotel Livemax Yokohama Tsurumi, Japan
#2 256574               Hidatei Hanaougi, Japan
#3 256576                Hotel Kashimaso, Japan
```

Or the `data.table` way

```
setDT(df)[, name := paste0(name, ", Japan")]
df
#      sku                                  name
#1: 256573 Hotel Livemax Yokohama Tsurumi, Japan
#2: 256574               Hidatei Hanaougi, Japan
#3: 256576                Hotel Kashimaso, Japan
```

Or the `tidyverse`/`dplyr` way

```
df %>% mutate(name = paste0(name, ", Japan"))
#    sku                                  name
#1 256573 Hotel Livemax Yokohama Tsurumi, Japan
#2 256574               Hidatei Hanaougi, Japan
#3 256576                Hotel Kashimaso, Japan
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "     sku                           name
1 256573 'Hotel Livemax Yokohama Tsurumi'
2 256574               'Hidatei Hanaougi'
3 256576                'Hotel Kashimaso'", header = T, row.names = 1)
```